# mongodb on AWS ec2 redhat linux

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install mongodb on my production instance, [following this tutorial](http://blog.gbinghan.com/2012/08/amazon-ami-install-mongodb-driver.html).
Everything seems to be fine, im seeing mongo on `info.php` and the sample connection is working.
But, when i run `mongod` or `service mongod start` from command line
i get `mongod: unrecognized
 service`

Also when i run `sudo find / -type f -name *mongo*` this is what i get.

```
/home/userName/.npm/mongodb/1.1.3/package/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js
/home/userName/.npm/mongodb/1.1.3/package/lib/mongodb/connection/mongos.js
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so
/usr/share/pear/.registry/.channel.pecl.php.net/mongo.reg
/usr/share/vim/vim72/keymap/mongolian_utf-8.vim
```

**question** what am i missing?
Up until now i have been testing locally on a windows machine.

Comment: Word of caution: IO is *very* slow on AWS unless you are using their new guaranteed IOPS offering.  You can improve IO by striping EBS instances into a software RAID configuration, but it is still relatively slow.  MongoDB is *extremely* sensitive to slow IO.  If your working set (frequently accessed documents) is larger than available RAM, things may get unacceptably sluggish.

Comment: @EricJ. i see. the ec2 install is for testing off of localhost, once we are ready planned on moving this again to a proper environment

Comment: P-IOPS and similar are good, it's true, but it's also worth pointing out that this is true of any access to disk.  EBS is slower than a local disk, yes, but you always want to have your working set in memory for best performance, even an SSD is an order of magnitude slower.  There are lots and lots of people running MongoDB on EC2 - when you start to hit memory limitations on a single instance, then it is time to upgrade the instance (of possible), improve memory utilization (plenty of posts on that), or shard and scale out horizontally.

Comment: And don't make the FourSquare mistake of waiting until you are exceeding the capability of the system before beginning to shard.  http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1265191137/foursquare-mongodb-outage-post-mortem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the database package itself (you have so far installed all the libraries to connect to it, but not the database).  Follow the instructions here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-redhat-centos-or-fedora-linux/

And you will have the appropriate service as needed.